# Is there a way to provide a tool tip or similar for a HTML input field?

Tags: html

I have a html input field for which I would like to provide some additional information when typing in this field or hovering the mouse over it. I have tried the following construct:

```
<input type="text" onmouseover="window.status='hello world'; return true;" name="TextInput" tabindex="2" maxlength="8" class="input">
```

but nothing happens when I type in this field or move the mouse pointer over this field.

Is there a *simple* way to achieve this?

Comment: I wonder why the downvotes occur. This is a specific programming problem which could be answered.

Comment: Probably because it's something that could be answered with a simple google search.

Comment: Well, I tried a simple google search, but nothing came up! Especially when I do not know what terms to search for. You do a search for 'form' 'title' or something and - bang have hundreds of hits. But not knowing that 'title' is the right term and 'tooltip' is the wrong term it seemed appropriate to me to ask this question here. I also wonder, if this is so simple, why people give a downvote instead of simple answering this seemingly easy question. AFAIK asking easy-to-answer questions are not forbidden on SO. Or do I see this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TITLE attribute for this. Pretty easy:

```
<input type="text" title="enter details here" />
```

Comment: @Alex Please mark as correct answer if this was helpful